# Rewrite share link url in iframe to website where embedded

Tags: database, url, iframe, url-rewriting, iframe-resizer

I have been googleling for a while now, but i can't seem to find a right solution.

I'm working for a chiptuning company that also develops software and has about 200 dealers worldwide who use our tools and tuningsoftware. Some of our dealers have our database tool implemented on their website. With this tool you can find your car and the options we offer.

We are redesigning our database tool and making it a standalone tool. We outsourced this to a developer, but he didnt have a solution for the problem i'm having. But I think everything can be solved right? :)
So, our old tool is built in our website, which was a hassle when we wanted to change our website. So a standalone tool it is. Now we have a little problem. In the tool we have a share link option. You can copy the link to the specific car results. But, of course, the share link gives us the absolute link for where the tool is developed.

We have 20+ websites that are all built around the tool and provided us with a absolute link to share. Now...the new tool is standalone and runs on a different website. The new tool will be loaded in an iframeresizer (https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer).

We have hundreds of custom links based on model, type and engine, so it's a long list, but for each website the last part is always the same, it's generated from our own database.

Is there a workaround to just get the last part of the url (which displays the make, model and engine), set a condition for each website that the url has to start with a specific website base url and having it paste that last part after that? Without having to really implement something in each website? It's only to copy the link and send it to someone.

Hope to hear from you someone! Thanks so much!

I haven't tried anything, because i have no idea where to start..And google is not really helping me because i don't know what to look for. And our developer doesn't think it can be done.